# jQuery on method with three events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having three events in my jQuery. But it seems like it only works with up to two events. This works only when I comment the first function. jQuery can handle three events in one on method? The following code does not work so I had to repeat the same thing with the same selector.

```
            var t;
            $("#pro").on("mouseleave",
                // function(){$("#foo").hide(10000)},
                function(){clearTimeout(t)},
                function(){t=setTimeout(function(){$("#detail").slideUp();}, 5000)}
            );
```

Here is my repeating.

```
          $("#pro").on("mouseleave", function(){$("#foo").fadeOut(10000)});
```

What should I do to include all events in one on method so that I do not have to repeat. Thanks,

Comment: Why do want to execute three functions on one event? Why not execute one function that does three things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create only one event handler:

```
var t;
$("#pro").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $("#foo").hide(10000);
    clearTimeout(t);
    t=setTimeout(function(){$("#detail").slideUp();}, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write all of them in a signle handler

```
       $("#pro").on("mouseleave",
            // function(){$("#foo").hide(10000)},
            function(){
                 clearTimeout(t);
                 t=setTimeout(function(){$("#detail").slideUp();}, 5000);
                 $("#foo").fadeOut(10000);
            }
        );
```